# How to remove the halo/glow around a marker upon hovering a series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I want to remove the "glow" from around those circles. Those paths you see are the glows themselves, not the marker with the 2px red and blue solid rings. So, remove those path elements.

There should be a setting in highcharts that allows me to disable/modify this "glow."

These elements are not rendered immediately when the chart is rendered. They are rendered when you start interacting with the chart, which means selecting them and removing them manually doesn't seem to work.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the size of the halo hover effect with `plotOptions`, for example ([JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ey8oh027/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        states: {
            hover: {
                enabled: true,
                halo: {
                    size: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some other options to customize the hover effect and the halo itself. [See the documentation here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.states.hover.halo). If you don't want the series to show any hover effect either you can just set `enabled: false`.

Comment: You sexy beast, you. Ty.